# Recover NiFi project

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

My Desktop crashed, and I recovered it.

However, my **NiFi** project disappeared. When I go to http://192.168.1.36:8080/nifi/ I see only a blank canvas. Is there a way to recure?

**NiFi** is installed on `/opt/nifi-1.10.0/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recover it if you have the `flow.xml.gz` present in archive directory. You can open `nifi.properties` and search for the property- nifi.flow.configuration.file. This property defined the flow file that will be loaded while starting the nifi.

Also, nifi takes the backup of `flow.xml` in a location which is defined by the property `nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir.`

You can replace the `flow.xml.gz` with the archive one and reboot the nifi.
The older flows will be recovered.